# What does "typedef int (*tMeshTable)(tOutPar *);" do?

Tags: c

While I went through some code, I found this declaration.

```
typedef int (*tMeshTable)(tOutPar *);
```

What is its intended purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tMeshtable typedef'd to be a pointer to a function taking an tOutPar pointer and returning an int.

It's easier to say tMeshTable than that whole thing every time.

So when you want to pass it around to a function, for instance:

```
void functionThatCallsFunction(tMeshTable myFunction) {
    tOutPar * outPar;
    /* This next line calls the function that was passed into this function as a parameter */
    int result = (*myFunction)(outPar);
}
```

it looks a lot cleaner than the raw function pointer syntax.

This page talks all about function pointers.  You should give it a look:  http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html

Comment: I think we need a better explanation. It's still confusing a bit.